# Showing correlation between two variables via scatterplot

Tags: r, plot, correlation

I am trying to show the correlation of government corruption and water quality using a scatterplot in R. I wanted to make an advanced one but can't seem to even do the most basic one.

Every time I type in `plot(water, corruption)` I get the message

```
error in plot(water) : object 'water' not found 
error in plot(corruption) : object 'corruption' not found
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide the code you used to generate the data, please? It is hard to diagnose the problem without knowing what `water` and `corruption` are.

Comment: Yyou need to have data first... the code you post would work if you had a vector called `water` and another one called `corruption`. Maybe those are column names of a data frame? Then you could do `plot(my_data$water, my_data$corruption)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the dataframe in which the variables are to be found. Here's an example using the `iris` dataframe:

```
plot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data=iris)
```

The ~ symbol is used in formulas, and can be interpreted as "as a function of". For a scatterplot, you thus put the y variable on the left and the x on the right.

Alternatively, you can use a comma to define the `x` and `y` axes as shown below:

```
plot(iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Sepal.Length)
```

*Note the change:* The first object (`iris$Sepal.Width`) refers to the x-axis and the second object refers to the y-axis (`iris$Sepal.Length`).